What is the difference between aarch64-none-elf and arm-none-eabi?
From what I undestand, aarch64-none-elf targets 64-bit ARMv8-A, while arm-none-eabi targets 32-bit ARMv7 and earlier, it cannot compile for aarch64, right?. Aarch64-none-elf uses ELF, while arm-none-eabi uses EABI. Aarch64-none-elf should be more commonly used for modern devices, while arm-none-eabi is often used for older or more constrained systems. Can anyone give me a more comprehensive and clear explanation?

EABI is an older notation.  It is elf.  There was very old arm-none-oabi compiler.  ARM updated the calling conventions at some point.  So the Aarch64-none-elf (elf portion) and arm-none-eabi (eabi portion) are not referring to the same thing.  You don't really have a question that can be answered.  It is correct that each target different architectures (compare to clang and -mthumb options).

arm-none-eabi can target AArch32 state of ARMv8, like arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a53 allows using ARMv8 new instructions (that were added to 32-bit mode).  So yes it's the 32-bit ISA, with ARM or Thumb mode machine code, but it's not limited to ARMv7 and older.

Well, there are two conceptual issue.  You can use arm-none-eabi to produce code that can run on a new ARMv8 CPU, but it is a compatibility mode.  You do not get the advanced 64 bit registers.  So, ARMv8 CPUs support output of the legacy 32bit instruction (for user mode), but you will need OS compatibility generally for this to work (which is fine if you use Linux or something else).  But here is where the question is nebulous (as none implies bare metal).  Bare metal can switch to 32bit only after 64bit boot; but really just use the 64 bit compiler.  This seems esoteric.

ARM architecture is (now) divided into 64 and 32 bit variants, but there is no "old" and "new" in the sense that the 32-bit architecture is far from obsolete.  New 32-bit ARM MCU devices used widely in embedded systems are available and in planned roadmaps for years to come.
64-bit devices are typically in the "application processor" sector (denoted by the -A suffix in ARMv8-A). ARMv8-M and ARMv8-R based MCUs remain 32-bit - but not at all "old" or legacy.
The "bare-metal" toolchain you use should match the architecture of the device you are targeting.

... everything from ARMv6-M onward is current in various device sectors, one architecture "version" does not necessarily obsolete another.

The instruction sets are completely incompatible.  The gnu folks, chose to separate them into different toolchains if you will.  The gnu sources can create a mips toolchain, a pdp-11 toolchain,   The 64 bit instruction set, aarch64, is new in that its origins came much much later than the 32 bit instruction set.  Yes both are very alive and well.   The ABI is the abi, you can get a working chain for the 32 bit instruction set without the word eabi in it.  The triplets do have some value but at the same time try not to dig too deeply into the triplet.
